Testing Flakiness with DispatchQueue.main.async
I'm experiencing flakiness when asserting that code runs on the main thread. Locally, the test passes even when run repeatedly, but on CI, it sometimes fails with the error: "Exceeded timeout of 10 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations." Here is a simplified version of my code:
// =================== Production code
final class TestClass {
  var testProtocol: TestProtocol

  init(testProtocol: TestProtocol) {
    self.testProtocol = testProtocol
  }

  func funcToTest() {
    performUIUpdate {
      testProtocol.doSomething()
    }
  }
}

func performUIUpdate(using closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
  if Thread.isMainThread {
    closure()
  } else {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: closure)
  }
}

protocol TestProtocol {
  func doSomething()
}

// =================== Test
final class TestProtocolMock: TestProtocol {
  var doSomethingClosure: (() -> Void)?
  func doSomething() {
    doSomethingClosure?()
  }
}

func test_funcToTest_thenDoSomethingExecuteOnMainQueue() { // the flaky test
  let testProtocol = TestProtocolMock()
  testProtocol.doSomethingClosure = {
    // then
    XCTAssertTrue(Thread.isMainThread)
    expectation.fulfill()                      // =========>> timeout error
  }
  let sut = TestClass(testProtocol: testProtocol)

  // when
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    sut.funcToTest()
  }

  wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10)
}

When I increase the timeout, the errors seem to occur less frequently. I'm not sure whether the flakiness comes from DispatchQueue.main.async. Besides mocking the main queue, are there other ways to make the test more stable?
Update
As Rob mentioned (link), DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background) might not run. Another variation of testing for main-thread execution also exhibits flakiness.
  func funcToTest() {
    Task() {
      aService.request() {
        performUIUpdate {
          testProtocol.doSomething()
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Test
  func test_funcToTest_thenDoSomethingExecuteOnMainQueue() { // the flaky test
  testProtocol.doSomethingClosure = {
    // then
    XCTAssertTrue(Thread.isMainThread)
    expectation.fulfill()                      // =========>> timeout error
  }
  let sut = TestClass(testProtocol: testProtocol)

  // when
  sut.funcToTest()

  wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10)
}


please provide when you are calling funcToTest()?, is anProtocol.doSomething() same as  testProtocol.doSomething()?, sut.handleErrorWithCompletion function implementation?

Hi Immanuel,
That was a mistake. I have updated the snippet. It should be sut.funcToTest().

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background) is not a "general purpose background queue." It is the lowest-possible priority. In some cases it may not even run.
(emphasis added)

The quality-of-service class for maintenance or cleanup tasks that you create.


Background tasks have the lowest priority of all tasks. Assign this class to tasks or dispatch queues that you use to perform work while your app is running in the background.

You very rarely mean this priority. You mean .default. Sometimes .utility (but usually .default). For a unit test, you would never mean it.

Thank you, Rob, for sharing your insights.
Do you have any suggestions for testing this case? Specifically, I'm looking to demonstrate that TestProtocol.doSomething is performed on the main thread.

Additionally, there are other cases where funcToTest is structured as shown below, and in these tests, I don't use DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background). The flakiness also occurs in these scenarios.
func funcToTest() {
    Task() {
      aService.request() { [weak self] in
        performUIUpdate {
          self?.testProtocol.doSomething()
        }
      }
    }
  }


This code doesn't compile, so I can't reproduce this problem. I would first expect that you have an actual deadlock bug that this test is exposing. Break this down to a minimal reproducible example to find that bug. The most common cause in my experience of "flaky" tests is bugs in the code under test.
